# create "no-op" version of a dll?

Tags: c++, windows, security, dll

Suppose I have an application app.exe which does a load-time link to d.dll, which in turn does a load-time link to dangerous.dll. Suppose that dangerous.dll is considered to have various security vulnerabilities. Suppose also that none of the functionality in dangerous.dll is needed by app.exe, and app.exe does not make any calls to d.dll that require it to use any functions in dangerous.dll.

I want to distribute the app without dangerous.dll, and ideally with minimal or no modifications to app.exe or d.dll. If I just remove dangerous.dll, I get a loading error when starting app.exe because it loads d.ll and d.dll tries to load dangerous.dll, which fails.

**Option 1**

I could make a "no-op" version of dangerous.dll, that provided all the same export function signatures as dangerous.dll, but had no-op code for all the exported functions themselves. That might not be too bad. I wonder if there already exists a tool that can take a .dll file and output another .dll file that has the same export functions, but ones that do nothing? This has the disadvantage that my no-op version of dangerous.dll would still be visible to the user, and it would look like my application still has the vulnerabilities in dangerous.dll.

**Option 2**

I wonder if there is some way, without building d.dll from source, I could hack d.dll so that it does not attempt a load-time load of dangerous.dll. It would be okay if this caused any calls from d.dll to a dangerous.dll function to fail/crash, since as I say app.exe should not cause d.ll to use any of the functions in dangerous.dll.

Comment: Hook `LoadLibrary` so that `dangerous.dll` is never loaded. Hook `GetProcAddress` so that it never loads any functions from `dangerous.dll` by returning null.

Comment: @Brandon, no functions in dangerous.dll are being called. I just don't want dangerous.dll to have to be shipped with my application.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source for d.dll, then just fix it to not load/use dangerous.dll.

If you don't have the source, just build a dangerous.dll with stub implementations for all exported functions.

Case closed. Move on and spend your time on more productive stuff.